# How to make a symlink in a deployed website

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, symlink

I am new in Laravel, as you know in order to access stored files you should have a symlink from storage/app/public to public/storage. In computer you can just type in command line: php artisan storage:link. But now I have deployed my website on hosting and want to create a symlink. How can I do it?

Comment: Is it a shared hosting?

Answer (score 1):

Just create a symlink in a php file and upload it to your public folder then navigate to it through your browser. 
The links must be absolute path....

```
$targetFolder = '/home/account_name/laravel/storage/app/public';

$linkFolder = '/home/account_name/public_html/storage';

symlink($targetFolder, $linkFolder);

echo 'Done!'
```

Lets save the file as link.php and upload it then navigate to it via http://your_site.com/link.php

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is near impossible on shared hosting since you would need a shell access to create the same symlink like on your computer.

Depending on your options maybe [Laravel Forge](https://forge.laravel.com/) is helpful to you.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you can add in the "**scripts**" tag of your composer a call to create the link after the deploy of your project:

`composer.json` file:

```
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "php artisan optimize"
        "php artisan storage:link"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "php artisan optimize"
        "php artisan storage:link"
    ]
}
```

This will cause the link to be created every time a `**composer update**` or `**composer install**` call occurs.

If the storage folder is not created, you will receive:

```
The [public / storage] directory has been linked.
```

If it is already created:

```
The "public / storage" directory already exists.
```

See also this discussion that may help you: https://github.com/laravel/internals/issues/34

Comment: Then how can I invoke composer update or composer install to make it do a symlink ? And is it the best practice of making this symlink ?

Comment: When you deploy a laravel application, this includes mandatory checking dependencies (calling composer update or composer install). If you do not do this manually, the system that deploys your laravel app does it.
Now if this is a good practice, the discussion that I quoted the link has several different opinions, now this way I quoted is also quoted a bit differently by barryvdh who is one of the biggest contributors to the laravel community.

Comment: Added that to composer.json but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Cron job does the trick for me on shared hosting.
Simply configure cron job to run the command the next minute (or a specific close time), and delete it after.

For example, this will run the command at 9:30am and log any output to `myjob.log`

```
30 9 * * * /path/to/php /path/to/artisan storage:link >> /path/to/myjob.log 2>&1
```

Comment: And how can I configure cron job ?

Comment: Depends on your host, On CPanel, there should be an icon there (mostly at the bottom) with the name Cron or Cron Job. You can contact your host to confirm this

Comment: Yes there is a cron job but it asks me to enter the file name in it. for instance cron.php. And what shout be written in cron.php ? exec('smth') ? or <?php exec('smth') ? or just smth or ? tell me please.

Comment: I'm trying to imagine what your cron interface looks like. if it's requesting for something like file and parameters/arguments then the file to run is `artisan` and the parameter/argument will be `storage:link`

Comment: No it only requires file. it is 000webhost hosting. you just type the name of the file.

Comment: Looks like the 000webhost hosting interface doesn't allow file value of this form `artisan storage:link` (You can try though). An alternative can be what you suggested, creating a cron.php file with  `<?php exec('/path/to/php artisan storage:link'); `. If none of them works, you can contact 000webhost support to see how to properly set it up.